# Updating the value of null String in JAVA?

Tags: java, string

Hi Have a java class with two methods as below.

```
public class HelloWorld
{
    public static  void main(String[] args)
    {
        String a=null;
        returnOriginalString(a);
        System.out.println(a);
        a="Hello";
        System.out.println(a);
    }

    private static void returnOriginalString(String a)
    {
        a="Hello World";
    }


}
```

when i print the above message i still get String a as null even after changing the string in second method.And one more thing if i update the string in same method it returns the correct value.How can i update the value of a without using any String methods.?

Comment: That code shouldn't even compile much less return null

Comment: Please show your real compilable and runnable code, including your main method, code that we can run ourselves. Note that a Java compiler is unforgiving, and you need a degree of OCD-ness to code (and to ask questions on this site).

Comment: updated the code.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels And to answer them ;-)

Comment: @user207421: true that :D

Comment: There is no such thing as a null string. There are only null references.

Comment: There are no [tag:arrays] or [tag:spring] here. Don't tag indiscriminately.

Comment: @user207421: case in point :)

Answer (score 0):

**Why does this happen?**

Java is 'pass by value' - when you pass a parameter to a method, the value of that parameter is passed. In the case of an object, the value being passed is the reference to the object.

This is where it gets interesting - you'd think that if you changed the contents of the string, then the change would also be seen outside the method - due to the reference being passed in. And if this was some other type of object (like List, for example), that would be true.

But Strings are immutable. When you create a new one (as in `a="Hello World";`), you get a new reference - the existing String object (with the reference that was passed into the method) does not have its contents changed.

**How do I fix it?**

It can be fixed by returning the new String from the `returnOriginalString` method and assigning it to `a` in the main method:

```
a = returnOriginalString();
```

Comment: Nothing to do with it. The question is why the variable `String a` in `main()` isn't updated, and this isn't the reason.

Comment: If you disagree that your original answer had nothing to do with it, why did you feel a need to change it? You can't have it both ways. And the fact that Strings are immutable continues to have exactly nothing to do with it. The same would apply to any object.

Comment: As I've already said, the same is true of `a = <anything>`.  It's an assignment, and it loses the previous value of `a`. Immutably has nothing to do with it. And I've never actually met anyone who should think that `a = <something>` is the same as `a,set<something>(...)`. It's not a 'common mistake' at all, it's just something you dreamed up yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Updating the method parameter value does not update the value of `String a` of `returnString()`. You need to return a String from `returnOriginalString(String a)` and then assign the string to `a`.

```
class HelloWorld
{
   public String returnString()
  {
    String a=null;
    a=returnOriginalString();
    System.out.println(a)
      a="Hello"
    System.out.println(a)
   }

   public static String returnOriginalString()
   {
     return "Hello World;"
   }
}
```

Comment: Dunno who would downvote this, but it's the correct answer.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this only explains one way to fix it - not why it happens in the first place.

Comment: @Jason I agree, it doesn't, but neither does your statement that Strings are immutable. The real reason is that Java is pass-by-reference, which neither of you stated. It was me who did that, by closing it as a duplicate.